# How to create a Ninject scope per user?

Tags: c#, ninject

For a Windows Phone application, where multiple users can login/logout, I would like to ensure that the objects created in the scope of one user (and reused for that user) is never reused when a new user logs in, ie. I need to wipe the internal state.

Is there any good practice on how to do that for Ninject? All I've been able to find is to create a custom scope object, which seems a bit ugly to me:

```
public sealed class UserScopeObject
{
}

public sealed class UserScope
{
    public static UserScopeObject Current { get; set; }
}

Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>().InScope(x => UserScope.Current);
```

And then whenever a user logins/logouts:

```
UserScope.Current = new UserScopeObject();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't re-create the object graph when the user logs-in, the scope is not going to help you. It can't "steal" an user-specific object from some non-user specific object.

So you'll need to recreate the object tree. If you do so, do you even require a scope? Could you not just unreference the user-specific part of the tree on logout, and recreate it on login?

It's only needed if you need something like a "singleton per user". If so, you may use a custom user-scope like you're doing (hint: you can do `UserScopeObject : INotifyWhenDisposed` to have Ninject release all scoped object as soon the `UserScopeObject` is disposed), or you could also use some other scope like Named Scope (see the [Named Scope Extension](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.namedscope/wiki)).

If you're re-creating part of the object tree whenever a user sign's in, you could have the user-specific root-node `DefinesNamedScope("User")` and all object which can't be transient / need to be "singleton" in regards to the user could be defined `.InNamedScope("User")`.

Maybe you could even achieve what you want with "InCallScope()".